# How to effectively replace sentences in word document with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

This is what I made so far :

```
from docx import Document

document = Document('filename.docx')

dic = {
    'Stack':'Stack Overflow',
'October 18 2021' : 'Actual Date'}
for p in document.paragraphs:
    inline = p.runs
    for i in range(len(inline)):
        text = inline[i].text
        for key in dic.keys():
            if key in text:
                 text=text.replace(key,dic[key])
                 inline[i].text = text


document.save('new.docx')
```

But it seems that this function works fine when she need to replace one word, but whn she need to replace sentences, it doesn't work (here October 18 2021)/

Any ideas why sentences doesn't work ?

Comment: The word doc is an xml file internally. The sentences usually have additional non-printing elements that mean that finding a match to replace is non-trivial.

Comment: What do you mean by non-trivial ?

Comment: A simple sentence (```This is non-trivial```) where I applied and removed some formatting ```<w:t>This</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidRPr="004E7E17"><w:rPr><w:lang w:val="en-US"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> is non</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:b/><w:bCs/><w:i/><w:iCs/><w:lang w:val="en-US"/></w:rPr><w:t>-</w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidRPr="004E7E17"><w:rPr><w:lang w:val="en-US"/></w:rPr><w:t>trivial</w:t>```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that part of the sentences you're reading are in fact in different runs.

As stated by scanny in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55269663/what-is-run-level-content-in-python-docx) post:

> So runs can effectively break up the text of a paragraph at arbitrary locations, even one run per character. In short, Word doesn't try to keep track of sentences; if you see a run that is a sentence that is pure coincidence.

One easy way to solve this problem is to do your search and replace using `paragraph.text` instead of `inline.text`

```py
from docx import Document

document = Document('test.docx')

dic = {
    'Stack':'Stack Overflow',
    'October 18 2021' : 'Actual Date'
}
for p in document.paragraphs:
    for key in dic.keys():
        if key in p.text:
            p.text = p.text.replace(key,dic[key])

document.save('new.docx')
```